# Is Rurouni Kenshin going to start back up now that Nobuhiro Watsuki has been fined?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin

So recently, the *Rurouni Kenshin* series, *Rurouni Kenshin: Hokkaido Arc*, was put on hiatus for the author's, Nobuhiro Watsuki, involvement in child pornography (On a side note, I think this is a very despicable thing, and I do NOT support it in any way, shape, form, or fashion). As I understand it, he was fined for the action and not put in jail.

Will the story resume now that this scandal has been mostly dealt with? (Again, I do not condone Nobuhiro Watsuki's actions at all, but I am a big fan of the *Rurouni Kenshin* series)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Rurouni Kenshin: The Hokkaido Arc* will continue in July issue of *Jump Square*, which will be published on June 4, 2018.

> [...] This June, it will resume serialization in Japan.
>
> [...]
>
> Starting June 4, however, *Rurouni Kenshin*'s "Hokkaido Arc" will return to print. [...]
>
> Continuing, it added, "The author spends his days reflecting and with remorse, and think as though it's our obligation as a publisher as well as his as an author make a way for us to reply through the work to the various opinions we've been getting, and so, from the July issue, which goes on sale June 4, serialization will resume.”

Source: [Kotaku](https://kotaku.com/rurouni-kenshin-will-resume-publication-this-june-in-ja-1825461597)

Answer (score -3):

[Source](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2018-06-04/rurouni-kenshin-hokkaido-arc-does-not-return-in-viz-shonen-jump/.132432)

> Viz Media's English digital edition of Weekly Shonen Jump did not publish a new chapter for Nobuhiro Watsuki's Rurouni Kenshin: Hokkaido Arc manga in Monday's issue. The series resumed from hiatus in Shueisha's Jump SQ. magazine in Japan on Monday.
>
> The manga went on hiatus last December following Watsuki being charged for possession of child pornography. Watsuki was later fined 200,000 yen (about US$1,900) in February.
>
> Viz Media was simultaneously publishing it in English before the manga went on hiatus.
>
> At the time of the manga's hiatus, Shueisha commented that it is taking this news seriously, and that Watsuki expresses deep regret. When it announced the manga's return, the magazine noted that Watsuki is living a life of reflection and atonement, but that Shueisha and Watsuki decided that continuing the manga to answer the desires of fans was a matter of duty.
>
> Watsuki and his novelist wife/story collaborator Kaoru Kurosaki launched the Rurouni Kenshin: Hokkaido Arc (Rurouni Kenshin, Meiji Kenkaku Romantan: Hokkaido-hen) manga in Shueisha's Jump SQ. magazine last September.

Comment: So, it will or will it not?

Comment: Right now it "resumes the hiatus" which means it is not being published but that can change once some kind of deal is made (or the lure of money becomes too big). For some reason someone downvoted my answer despite it clearly answering the question.

Comment: Its just a quote and hardly an answer. Please summarize the point of your quote if you wish to make an answer out of it.

Comment: The quote is self evident, frankly. And a quote stating facts is better than a random internet dude (me) repeating stuff with his own words. Less "telephone game" problems that way.

Comment: It may be to you, but I disagree. Low effort answer don't make for good answers. If you can't take the time to write at least an summary explaining the relevant details in context, then you should not be making an answer.